# Difficult probability exercise of modelisation using finite sample spaces (where P is not uniform)

Tags: probability-theory

I'm looking for an example of *finite* probability space where the definition of $\mathbb{P}$ is not obvious. (**edit**: what I mean here is that finding appropriate prior probabilities to model the problem is a difficult exercise)

For instance, if I draw a ball in an urn containing 3 red balls and 2 blacks balls, it is quite obvious that the probability $\mathbb{P}(R)$ to draw a red ball is $3/5$. This "obvious" probability assignment can be obtained by using using a "hidden" equiprobability on the space of numbered balls $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5\}$ where the first three balls are supposed to be red and the last two are supposed to be black.

I am looking for an example where assigning the prior probability $\mathbb{P}(R)$ is not obvious at first and where the use of a hidden equiprobability space is necessary to find the value of $\mathbb{P}(R)$ for a correct modelisation.

Another way to frame this question is : difficult problem concerning modelisation with finite sample space.

Comment: In many applications the actual definition of $\mathbb P$ is not really of concern; rather we are interested in (functions of) distributions of random variables. One need not specify a sample space and a probability measure to speak of many probabilistic topics.

Comment: @Math1000 this is most definitely true but I am explicitly looking for an "exercise" using *finite* sample spaces

Answer (score 1):

I do not remember where I saw the following problem; it's certainly classical. The probability itself is the uniform one, but it's not completly obvious. Perhaps you were looking for harder/more complicated ones ?

---

500 families with two children each live in a town. There are 500 boys and 500 girls. Knock at a door of a house at random; if a girl answers, ask her if her sibling is a sister or a brother. If it's a boy who answers, excuse yourself and just go to another random house, until a girl answers.

Question: What is the probability you were told "I have a sister" ?

Comment: Hi @user120527, thank you for you interest in my question and this very interesting exercise (+1). This is not what I am looking for because the difficulty here (unless I'm mistaken) comes from non independence of the repartition between families and not the non uniformity of the sample space.